# Swift error "Could not find overload for '==' that accepts..."

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I have been building in xCode and juts came across this error in an if statement:
`Could not find overload for '==' that accepts that accepts the supplied arguments`

here is the code that is generating it

```
if (err == nil && token != nil) {
    ...
}
```

the err is of type `let err: NSError?` and the token is `var token = body as! NSString`

It seems to be the first condition that is causing the error. Any help or advice would be great.

Comment: What are the types of `err` and `token`? I'd guess one or both of them isn't an Optional.

Comment: I haver updated the question, looks like the err is an optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `token` is not an Optional since you're using `as!`.

Get rid of the forced typecast to solve this, make `token` an Optional too:

```
let token = body as? NSString
```

By the way, you don't need the brackets around the condition, you can write it like this:

```
if err == nil && token != nil {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where I defined an int and if the user entered a number, it would store it.  I had a case where if a user didn't enter it....if (number == nil), I had the same issue.  Since I defined it as an int, it didn't like having it empty, so I converted the int to a string and it worked.

So maybe find where you are defining "err" and "token" and see if a conversion or something might be necessary.  var stringError = err and force it using ! or cast as String(err).